# Azure SQL DWH - Problem with CTE and random sample

Tags: sql, azure, common-table-expression, azure-synapse

I querying an Azure SQL Data warehouse (aka Azure Synapse) with version:

```
Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15554.0 Dec 10 2020
```

So I have a table with events and additional data that looks like this:

```
    event_id  |  date    | field3    | field4 |.......  
        1     |  10/20   | ......    | ...... |.......  
        2     |  10/21   | ......    | ...... |.......  
        3     |  10/22   | ......    | ...... |.......  
        1     |  10/20   | ......    | ...... |.......
```

I want to get a sample of 10 events that appear twice in the table, so it should return 20 rows.
I am trying to do it with a CTE, to get 10 event_id that appear twice. Then in the SELECT clause I can use the CTE to filter and get the rest of the information:

```
 -- CTE
 -- get sample of 10 event_id
 -- that appear twice
WITH SPL_2_ROWS AS 
(SELECT TOP 10 event_id, COUNT(*) AS q_rows
FROM report_table
GROUP BY event_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY NEWID())
-- Main Query
-- get all the information for the 
-- previous 10 event_id
SELECT REP.*
FROM report_table  REP
WHERE event_id IN
(SELECT event_id FROM SPL_2_ROWS)
```

The problem I'm having is that it returns what it looks like a random number of
rows (something between 10 and 30). That shouldn't happen because of the way the query is written.
I tried changing the  WHERE filter for a JOIN with the same results:

```
JOIN SPL_2_ROWS  SPL
  ON REP.event_id = SPL.event_id
```

Something strange is that if I use a temporal table instead of a CTE, the query works just fine.
**What am I missing here?**

**ADITIONAL INFO:**
The table has around 60 fields and 6M records, no primary key:
The DDL creation statement is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[report_table]
(
    [my_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [field2] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    ...
    ...
    ...
    [event_id] [int] NULL,
    [client_id] [int] NULL,
    [field30] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [field31] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [field32] [int] NULL,
    ...
    ...
    ...
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    HEAP
)
GO
```

Comment: What's the PK for `report_table`? Can you post the DDL you used to create that table?

Comment: @Kashyap, no primary key (I think synapse DWH doesn't support them). I updated the question to add the creation DDL. I didn't create this table, but used MS SSMS to get the CREATE script

Comment: `synapse DWH doesn't support them`: It does "support" them. But doesn't "enforce" them (it's used for building optimal execution plan). Asked because when you have a primary key and insert duplicates, it allows you to insert duplicates but then misbehaves when you do `select` from such corrupt table. "misbehaves" -> returns different number of results for different queries, which should've returned same number of rows.

Comment: So expectation is that it always returns 20 rows, right? Sounds very much like the PK related misbehavior I described above. Though I do see `even_id` is not PK in DDL. It's also possible to define a PK [using `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#g-creating-a-primary-key-constraint-with-index-or-data-compression-options). IIRC when you generate DDL using SSMS it comes as an ALTER not part of CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @Kashyap, SSMS allows many options, and the table doesn't have primary key anyway ![SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/media/scripting-ssms/scriptdb.png?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: So expectation is that it always returns 20 rows, right? In the output of "Main query" do you always get 10 distinct event ids (or more or less)? Can you post results (may be TOP 3-5) couple of times, when it returns different results? What happens if you `order by event_id` in CTE? Also what are you trying accomplish? I wonder if you can use `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` somehow. And finally, are you sure that when you generated DDL in SSMS word CONSTRAINT doesn't appear? Like `CONSTRAINT [Cnstr_asdfatre] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([event_id] ASC) NOT ENFORCED`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  But it might be simpler with aggregation and join:

```
select rt.*
from (select event_id, row_number() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
      from report_table rt
      group by event_id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) e join
     report_table rt
     on rt.event_id = e.event_id
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: This is not working properly either (I added the join condition e.seqnu<=10). I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or the sql engine is misbehaving

Comment: @Cristobal . . . What does "not working" mean?

Comment: It returns a randon number of rows (normally more than 20). It seems like for some reason it's assigning the same seqnum to different rows

Comment: @Cristobal . . . Are you sure you have the `having count(*) = 2` in the subquery?

Comment: yes, I checked multiple times. I think the same underlying reason that makes the CTE query behave strangely, also affects the subquery approach. It must be something specific to azure sql and how the newid funtion is handled. Luckily the temp table approach works, so I could get what I want, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cristobal . . . `newid()` shouldn't have an impact on this, because `row_number()` should return sequential values with no gaps regardless of the ordering criterion.  You can replace `newid()` by `event_id` to see if you at least get 20 rows.